# How to import multiple ontologies into neo4j with multiple labels for the owl:Class

Tags: neo4j, ontology, linked-data, neosemantics

I have 3 ontologies and I want to import them in the same graph in neo4j, but I would like to import each owl:Class of each ontology under a different label.
Any guidance or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple passes on your ontologies to add the additional custom labels. Sample code here:

https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-import-two-ontologies-with-two-different-labels-for-the-owl-class/54097/9?u=jesus.barrasa